# Get feature from two overlapping KML layers doesn't work

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, layers, getfeatureinfo

I did an implementation similar to http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html
The difference is that I have two or more kml layers at the same location and want to show their information combined.

The problem is that the *featureselected* layer's event fires only once, for the top most kml layer.

Does anyone know how to get this working, or a possible workarround?

Here is my code:

```
function createFetureInfoService() {
var wmsServerArray = [];
var dictionary = {};
var items = [];
var location;

for (var i = 0; i < wmsControls.length; i++) {
    wmsControls[i].deactivate();
}

for (var i = 0; i < kmlControls.length; i++) {
    mapa.removeControl(kmlControls[i]);
    kmlControls[i].deactivate();
}

kmlControls.length = 0;
wmsControls.length = 0;
totalWMSServerCount = 0;
currentWMSServerCount = 0;
totalKMLCount = 0;
currentKMLCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < mapa.getNumLayers(); i++) {
    layer = mapa.layers[i];
    if ((layer instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.WMS) && !layer.isBaseLayer) {
        if (!dictionary.hasOwnProperty(layer.url)) {
            totalWMSServerCount++;
            wmsServerArray.push(layer.url);
            dictionary[layer.url] = "";
        }
    }
    else if ((layer instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.Vector) && (layer.hasOwnProperty("options")) && (layer.options.hasOwnProperty("protocol")) &&
    (layer.options.protocol.hasOwnProperty("format")) && (layer.options.protocol.format instanceof OpenLayers.Format.KML) && !layer.isBaseLayer) {
        layer.displayOutsideMaxExtent = true;
        select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer);
        kmlControls.push(select);
        layer.events.on({
            featureselected: function (e) {
                var feature = e.feature;
                location = e.xy;
                items.push({
                    xtype: "propertygrid",
                    autoHeight: true,
                    title: feature.layer.name,
                    source: feature.attributes
                });
                currentKMLCount++;
                showGetFeaturePopup(items, location);
                feature.layer.selectedFeatures.length = 0;
            }
        });
        mapa.addControl(select);
        select.activate();
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < wmsServerArray.length; i++) {
    var wmsFeatureInfo = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: wmsServerArray[i],
        map: mapa,
        infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml"
    });
    wmsControls.push(wmsFeatureInfo);
    wmsFeatureInfo.events.on({
        getfeatureinfo: function (e) {
            location = e.xy;
            Ext.each(e.features, function (feature) {
                items.push({
                    xtype: "propertygrid",
                    autoHeight: true,
                    title: feature.fid,
                    source: feature.attributes
                });
            });
            currentWMSServerCount++;
            showGetFeaturePopup(items, location);
        },
        beforegetfeatureinfo: function (e) {
            this.layers = filterQueryableLayers(this.url);
            },
        nogetfeatureinfo: function (e) {
            currentWMSServerCount++;
            showGetFeaturePopup(items, location);
        }
    });
    wmsFeatureInfo.activate();
}
```

}

```
function showGetFeaturePopup(items, location) {
totalKMLCount = 0;
var layers = mapa.getLayersBy("visibility", true);    
for (var i = 0, len = layers.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ((layers[i] instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.Vector) && (layers[i].hasOwnProperty("options")) && (layers[i].options.hasOwnProperty("protocol")) &&
    (layers[i].options.protocol.hasOwnProperty("format")) && (layers[i].options.protocol.format instanceof OpenLayers.Format.KML) && !layers[i].isBaseLayer) {
        totalKMLCount++;
    }
}

if ((currentWMSServerCount + currentKMLCount) < (totalWMSServerCount + totalKMLCount))
    return;
currentWMSServerCount = 0;
currentKMLCount = 0;

if (items.length == 0)
    showInfoPopup(mapa.getLonLatFromPixel(location), 'Nenhuma informa\u00E7\u00E3o dispon\u00EDvel');
else {
    var popUp = new GeoExt.Popup({
        title: "Informa\u00E7\u00E3o sobre as Camadas WMS",
        layout: "accordion",
        anchored: false,
        resizable: true,
        map: mapa,
        location: location,
        items: items,
        autoScroll: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        unpinnable: false,
        draggable: true,
        closeAction: 'hide'
    });
    popUp.show();
}
items.length = 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to change file extension from kml to xml

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add some more details, such as why you think this will help?